# validating digital signature using SAML in eclipse and IBM RAD

Tags: java, eclipse, saml, opensaml, ibm-rad

I am using this java program to validate a digital signature using public key (cer file).  I am using opensaml 2.6.3 jars

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;



 import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;

 import java.security.KeyFactory;

 import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

 import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap;
import org.opensaml.common.xml.SAMLSchemaBuilder;

import org.opensaml.saml2.core.NewEncryptedID;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.Response;

 import org.opensaml.xml.Configuration;
import org.opensaml.xml.XMLObject;

 import org.opensaml.xml.io.Unmarshaller;
import org.opensaml.xml.io.UnmarshallerFactory;
import org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool;

 import org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509Credential;
import org.opensaml.xml.signature.Signature;
import org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator;
import org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException;


 public class FinalTester
 {

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
 try
 {
 //initialize the opensaml library
DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(); 

 Schema schema = SAMLSchemaBuilder.getSAML11Schema();

 //get parser pool manager
 BasicParserPool parserPoolManager = new BasicParserPool();
 parserPoolManager.setNamespaceAware(true);
 parserPoolManager.setIgnoreElementContentWhitespace(true);
 parserPoolManager.setSchema(schema);
////get KeyFactory object that creates key objects, specifying RSA
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");



 String state=
         "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";

 byte[] xmlString = Base64.decodeBase64(state);
String s = new String(xmlString);

 Document document = parserPoolManager.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF-8")));
 Element metadataRoot = (Element) document.getDocumentElement();



 QName qName= new QName(metadataRoot.getNamespaceURI(), metadataRoot.getLocalName(), metadataRoot.getPrefix());

// //get an unmarshaller
 Unmarshaller unmarshaller = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory().getUnmarshaller(qName);

// //unmarshall using the document root element
 Response response = (Response)unmarshaller.unmarshall(metadataRoot);




 //get the signature to validate from the response object
 Signature signature = response.getSignature();



 /***************************************************************************************************/

 //grab the certificate file
 File certificateFile = new File("C:\\samlwork\\domain.com_B64.cer"); 

 //get the certificate from the file
 InputStream inputStream2 = new FileInputStream(certificateFile);
 CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
 X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream2);
 inputStream2.close();

 //pull out the public key part of the certificate into a KeySpec
 X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(certificate.getPublicKey().getEncoded());




 //generate public key to validate signatures
 PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);



 //create credentials
 BasicX509Credential publicCredential = new BasicX509Credential();

 //add public key value
 publicCredential.setPublicKey(publicKey);

 //create SignatureValidator
 SignatureValidator signatureValidator = new SignatureValidator(publicCredential);



 //try to validate
 try 
 {
 signatureValidator.validate(signature);
 }
 catch (ValidationException ve) 
 {
 System.out.println("Signature is NOT valid.");
 System.out.println(ve.getMessage());
 return;
 }

 //no validation exception was thrown
 System.out.println("Signature is valid."); 

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 ex.printStackTrace();
 }
  }

 }
```

This code if i run this in eclipse it says that the signature is valid.  But if I run in RAD8.2 it says signature is invalid. Please help me with this. I am using different workspaces in rad and eclipse

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Signature did not validate against the credential's key is the message in RAD

Comment: @Stefan Signature did not validate against the credential's key is the message in RAD. But in eclipse, signature is validated correctly.

Comment: How you solve this error? I am facing same issue. Please guide... Thanks, Sayali

Comment: Can you @user4567570 try removing \n, \r, \t from String s.                                              byte[] xmlString = Base64.decodeBase64(state);
String s = new String(xmlString);                                                               s=s.replaceAll("[\\n\\r\\t]", "");